# Check whether message box is open WPF C#?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF application where the window  gets small and moved to the side if it gets deactivated. But I dont want this feature to happen if there is a messagebox open on the window. Is there a way we can check if there is any dialog box open in C# code?

Comment: "where the window gets small and moved to the side if it gets deactivated" - it would be helpful to know 1) if you did this yourself, or if you're talking about some sort of standard behavior 2) How you did this, in case there is some way to prevent that action specific to your app

Comment: I did the animation myself. If I can check whether the dialog box is open, I can tell my animation whether or not to perform the same.

Comment: Which kind of dialog box is it?

Comment: Messagebox.Show("some message")

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Wrap the call to your MessageBox in a static class/method. If this is called set a flag that your MessageBox is open.

*Something like this:*

```
  public class MessageBoxWrapper
  {
    public static bool IsOpen {get;set;} 

    // give all arguments you want to have for your MSGBox
    public static void Show(string messageBoxText, string caption)
    {
     IsOpen = true;
     MessageBox.Show(messageBoxText, caption);
     IsOpen = false;
    }
  }
```

*Usage:*

```
MessageBoxWrapper.Show("TEST","TEST");
MessageBoxWrapper.IsOpen
```

But you have to make sure to always use the Wrapper to call a MessageBox

Answer (score 1):

Set a flag somewhere when you open a MessageBox. Unset it when the MessageBox is closed.

Check the flag when you handling the deactivation.

If there's a possibility of more than one MessageBox being open at a time then you'll need to give that some thought, otherwise one closing will make it look like there are none open.

Comment: In case of more than one MessageBox, use a counter. Increase it when a MessageBox opens, decrease when it is closed.